# Using SQLiteAsyncConnection throwing a MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, sqlite, win-universal-app, portable-class-library, sqlite-net

First time using `SQLite`, opted for [SQLite.net-pcl](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL),

I have a `PCL` library, that I consume from my `UWP` app, my PCL library has the `DBContext` class :

```
public NewspaperDataContext(ISQLitePlatform sqLitePlatform, string applicationPath, string dataBaseName)
{
     _sqlConnection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(()=> new SQLiteConnectionWithLock(sqLitePlatform, 
     new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnectionString(Path.Combine(applicationPath, dataBaseName), storeDateTimeAsTicks: false)));

     CreateTableAsync(_sqlConnection, typeof(Article)).Result.Wait();
     CreateTableAsync(_sqlConnection, typeof(Author)).Result.Wait();
     CreateTableAsync(_sqlConnection, typeof(Category)).Result.Wait();
     CreateTableAsync(_sqlConnection, typeof(Group)).Result.Wait();

     var c = _sqlConnection.Table<Article>();
}

private async Task<Task> CreateTableAsync(SQLiteAsyncConnection asyncConnection, Type table)
{
     return asyncConnection.CreateTableAsync<Author>().ContinueWith((results) =>
     {
           Debug.WriteLine(!results.IsFaulted
           ? $"Error where creating the {nameof(table)} table !!"
           : $"Table {nameof(table)} created sucessfully!");
     });
}
```

I call the `NewspaperDataContext` from my UWP app like this :

```
private async void MainPage_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
    var n = new NewspaperDataContext(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "LiberteDB");
}
```

In the NewspaperDataContext constructor at the line :

```
var c = _sqlConnection.Table<Article>();
```

A strange MissingMethodException is thrown saying :

> An exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in
>   SQLite.Net.Async.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Method not found: 'Void
>   SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnectionString..ctor(System.String, Boolean,
>   SQLite.Net.IBlobSerializer, SQLite.Net.IContractResolver)'.

Couldn't find anything related to this error in the internet, please can someone help.

Comment: This exception is thrown when there is an attempt to dynamically access a method that does not exist. I think the problem is possible that you create a method `NewspaperDataContext` which must have a return type, but there is no return value in your code. And you call this method somehow like creating a new instance of a class named `NewspaperDataContext`. If this method is void kind, can you please try to call this method with this code `NewspaperDataContext(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "LiberteDB");`?

Comment: Or, if there is a return value, would you please try to call this method like `var n = NewspaperDataContext(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "LiberteDB");`? Sorry if I misunderstand your `NewspaperDataContext` method. But I think the problem may come with how you call this method.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this issue? I am having a similar problem

Comment: Found out that it was resharper adding in an old package that caused my issue. https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/issues/14

Answer (score 0):

The package `sqlite-net-pcl` should be added to only to PCL project. If you add it to any other platform such as Android, it will give this `MethodMissingException`. So, remove the package from other platforms as this package is required only for PCL project. I am giving this answer as I encountered the same issue and found the solution. I encountered this exception while developing apps using Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: from [here](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net): "Important: You will need to add the NuGet package to both your .NET Standard library project and your platform-dependent app project." - so maybe version dependent?